# Sendgrid GEM bug while sending plain/text e-mail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, sendgrid

Im tring to send an e-mail via the sendgrid gem for ruby on rails.
This is my code for the mailer:

```
def send_form(params)
  @params=params
  mail( :to => 'my_email',
    :subject => 'my_subject',:content_type => "text/plain")
end
```

It is loading my view which is *`send_form.json.erb`* and in the view there is this:

```
<%= raw @params.to_json %>
```

Now, the problem here is that the source code from the e-mail has 2 emails(?), one with plain text and one with HTML.

```
    This is a multi-part message in MIME format...

------------=_1448758618-20748-809
Content-Type: text/plain;
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

{"versao":"cee'd SW - 1.6 CRDi ISG EX","concessionario":"Sotabi","extraEmail":"gerencia@sotabi.p","nome":"Miguel Rebola","email":"miguelrebola21@gmail.com","telefone":"968823502","comentarios":"fdfd","autorizo":"yes"}

------------=_1448758618-20748-809
Content-Type: text/html; charset="UTF-8"
Content-Disposition: inline
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

<html><body>
<p>{&quot;versao&quot;:&quot;cee'd SW &ndash; 1.6 CRDi ISG EX&quot;,&quot;concessionario&quot;:&quot;Sotabi&quot;,&quot;extraEmail&quot;:&quot;gerencia@sotabi.p&quot;,&quot;nome&quot;:&quot;Miguel Rebola&quot;,&quot;email&quot;:&quot;miguelrebola21@gmail.com&quot;,&quot;telefone&quot;:&quot;968823502&quot;,&quot;comentarios&quot;:&quot;fdfd&quot;,&quot;autorizo&quot;:&quot;yes&quot;}</p>

<img src="https://u1373375.ct.sendgrid.net/wf/open?upn=u0x3fSBqEx-2Fl-2BmgujqmE8BQomXBLbogF-2Bc6F-2BtlRZ6DF0HBXi526k5pl8ZUC-2FxtIp9ic36mMF2aQ4d6eJ5Lqq9panqdI3Ye7hmz4ajbhDO44ePVyM2SMDDBBWWMpJ5l50gYvbwVmo7S80MmO-2BlSAaFwiQpqgTXdMFRmz0vHxy-2BdXYgxbqCs5K3msoeQ4SQS-2BZqoqDpo2wVLTeQrEbKzxE2cQn1u-2FORF6fYLTNqw560g-3D" alt="" width="1" height="1" border="0" style="height:1px !important;width:1px !important;border-width:0 !important;margin-top:0 !important;margin-bottom:0 !important;margin-right:0 !important;margin-left:0 !important;padding-top:0 !important;padding-bottom:0 !important;padding-right:0 !important;padding-left:0 !important;"/>
</body></html>
```

I need to send only the plain/text. Any idea??

Comment: This is actually a default format for HTML emails, they usually contain a plain-text part for legacy email clients lacking HTML support. As for teh auto-conversion, maybe this https://support.sendgrid.com/hc/en-us/articles/200181418-Plain-text-emails-converted-to-HTML? Also, have you tried setting `:html` to an empty string and using `:text` only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Needed to change the confgiuration on Sendrigd website.

Comment: Could you advice which one?

Comment: Dashboard, Settings, Plain Content

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings https://app.sendgrid.com/settings/mail_settings

find Plain Content parameter and switch it on.